How to make data retrieval from Room Fast
I am retrieving data from the room database using this code. it takes around 2 seconds to fetch and display data on the screen. The table has 10k rows.
Table
@Entity("RoomTrains")
data class TrnTable(
@PrimaryKey
val num:Int=0,
val name:String="",
val type:Int=0,
val srCode:String="",
val srcName:String="",
val destCode:String="",
val destName:String="",
val runDays:Int=0,
val classes:String="",
val totalDist:Float=0.0f,
val jourTime:Int=0,
val depArr:String="",
val updatedOn:Int=0)

Dao
@Query("SELECT * FROM RoomTrains")
abstract  fun getTrains(): Flow<List<TrnTable>>

Repository
fun getAllTrains(): Flow<List<TrnTable>> {
    return trainDao.getTrains()
}

View model
 val allTrainsFromTrnTableSF: StateFlow<List<TrnTable>> = chukRepository.getAllTrains()
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
        initialValue = emptyList(),
    )

UI Page
    val trainList by viewModel.allTrainsFromTrnTableSF.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
     LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray)) {
            items(trainList) { train ->
            //data displayed using Card()
              }
        }


Welcome to stackoverflow, if below solution solved your problem always consider it upvoting and accepting it. That's the way to appreciate the answerer.


I am retrieving data from the room database using this code. it takes around 2 seconds to fetch and display data on the screen. The table has 10k rows.

In this case you are getting all data from this table("RoomTrains"), if the table increases, so the time and memory consume probably will increase. Therefore, I'd suggest you work with pagination. In this way you can get the data as needed, for example, as the user scroll. Room library can delivery for you a PagingSource from your query, as exemplified below (example from Android documentation):
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE label LIKE :query")
fun pagingSource(query: String): PagingSource<Int, User>

As you are using Compose, it has this function collectAsLazyPagingItems, so you can collect the items. This Android documentation has a sample code.


Thank you so much for answering.
Now it took 8 milliseconds to get the first couple of rows, But I am using all rows and sorting and filtering them based on what the user wants to see.
For example user wants to see only superfast trains, certain trains originating from XYZ station, or user sorted list according to travel time.
Is this possible with Paging, if yes how?

You're welcome! You could create a "Query" that returns a PagingSource for each use case.

@heronsanches +1 Good answer I was also going to suggest pagination which works same way as indexing works in MySQL databases
